# wcf rest json return collection

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, wcf-data-services

I am attempting to build a *Restful WCF Service* which returns data in *JSON* format. My firsts methods work fine but when I try return a collection my test program receive the next exception:

> *Unable to write data to the transport connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

My Service code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{ 
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/GetModes")]
    OGetModesResponse OGetModes(OGetModesRequest oGetModes);
}
[DataContract]
public class OGetModesRequest
{
    private String m_sTicket;

    [DataMember]
    public String prTicket
    {
        get { return m_sTicket; }
        set { m_sTicket = value; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class OGetModesResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string sTicket;
    [DataMember]
    public emStatus emStatus;
    [DataMember]
    public IList<CTMode> aoModes;
}
```

And my test program:

```
OGetModesRequest oGetModes = new OGetModesRequest { prTicket = sTicket };
ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OGetModesRequest));
mem = new MemoryStream();
ser.WriteObject(mem, oGetModes);
webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
//Exception here
bData = webClient.UploadData("http://localhost:26104/Service.svc/GetModes", "POST", mem.ToArray()); 
stream = new MemoryStream(bData);
obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OGetModesResponse));
OGetModesResponse OResultModes = obj.ReadObject(stream) as OGetModesResponse;
```

I debug my services and works fine. What can be happening?

Thanks for help.

Edit (solution):
CTMode is a class used by managing object that I obtain using NHibernate so I create a new class serializable called CMode

```
[DataContract]
public class OGetModesResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string sTicket;
    [DataMember]
    public emStatus emStatus;
    [DataMember]
    public IList<CMode> aoModes;
}
[Serializable]
public class CMode
{
    public Int32 nId;
    public Int32 nCode;
    public String sName;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/687613/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection#answer2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check inner exception and add some logging/ trace on the server.

There are few possibilities for your (generic) error as you may not be aware about inner exception:

- object CTMode is missing DataContract, DataMember attribute.
- object CTMode is an enum that missing attributes or has incorrect value that cannot be serialized
- previous connection is not closed correctly
- there is a proxy server on the way and you need to bypassed it

Comment: The error only appears when IList<CTMode> != null. If the method return IList<CTMode> == null, everything works fine. There is not a  proxy server and connection closed correctly. I think that the problem is in CTMode serialized. CTMode class is used for work with  NHibernate object, I add this class to DataContract as you say. Apologize by the write format but I am noob writing in stackoverflow and I still not write correctly in this page.

Comment: I add new class to DataContract and now it works. I edited my answer to add the modication.Thanks Wojciech.